# Should diacritics be ignored in search? What about non-latin scripts?

Tags: search, language, localization

I am build a webapp. Should I ignore the diacritics in the search function?

I am non-native speaker myself and I prefer when search engines ignore/substitute for the diacritics of my language. [Others probably prefer it too](https://superuser.com/questions/850805/how-to-make-ctrlf-ignore-accents-and-diacritics-when-searching-on-page-in-googl) but is there a consensus?

And what should be the correct mapping? [Internet suggests this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990904/remove-accents-diacritics-in-a-string-in-javascript/18391901#18391901) but how authoritative it is?

And how about non-latin scripts? From what I know for instance Russian language has soft and hard consonants, what is the best practice there?

Comment: As a user I expect this when searching... Hopefully someone can point out any quirky mappings to be aware of.

Answer (score 1):

The question as to whether diacritics should be ignored in search functions will probably get down to personal preference/opinion. However, you may find the following useful:

- http://cognitiveseo.com/blog/6773/the-diacritics-seo-technique-a-tactic-nobody-is-using/
- https://moz.com/blog/so-you-want-to-know-about-foreign-language-seo-mozinar-q-a

**Note:** I have ***no*** affiliation with the above products/services.

However, in terms of the correct mapping in doing so, that's easier to answer. Without knowing what language you're building your web app in, you ***may*** find the following resources useful:

- [Diacritical Character to ASCII Character Mapping](http://Diacritical%20Character%20to%20ASCII%20Character%20Mapping)
- [Replacing diacritics in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/863800/replacing-diacritics-in-javascript)
- [PHP iconv function](http://php.net/manual/en/book.iconv.php)
- [PHP: Replace umlauts with closest 7-bit ASCII equivalent in an UTF-8 string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158241/php-replace-umlauts-with-closest-7-bit-ascii-equivalent-in-an-utf-8-string)
- [Code page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page)
- [Combining diacritics chart](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0300.pdf)
- [Combining character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character) (wikipedia article)

Hope this is useful. Good luck!